# I want to publish vue.js without using localhost or web server

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I developed a project with vue.js and got the project build. After the build I bought, I tried to open the index.html page in the dist folder, but it does not open, a blank screen appears. When I did some research, they wrote that the built projects should be installed on any server in order to work. The project I have built will work in a local tablet that does not connect to the internet. What path should I follow?

Note: I am using Vue 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible if you use the default vue cli to build your project, because the chunks are requested from a domain route. However this is possible if you compile all of your vue code into a single html file.

A quick google leads to this question:

[Vue combine into single html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58274001/vue-cli-combine-build-output-to-a-single-html-file)