# How to build a Nuxt 3 app using Webpack builder with HtmlWebpackPlugin?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, nuxt.js, html-webpack-plugin

I'm having issues setting up *HtmlWebpackPlugin* in a Nuxt 3 app using Webpack 5.

I'm getting an error while attempting this with a simple project. However, I was able to produce a successful build in another Vue project with similar steps (following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58309522/175510)).

How can one build a bundle using HtmlWebpackPlugin in the context of a *Nuxt* project?

Please provide additional config if necessary for a successful build.

Scenario: Build a single standalone HTML bundle file with all assets inlined and embedded (JS, CSS, images, etc.) to be usable offline, locally and directly in a browser.

The build error:

```
ERROR  Nuxt Build Error: Nuxt build error

  ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
  File was processed with these loaders:
  * ./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js
  * ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js
  * ./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js
  * ./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  > <!-- output-template.html -->
  | <!DOCTYPE html>
  | <html lang=en>
  at handleParseError (node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:982:19)
  at node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:1101:5
  at processResult (node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:806:11)
  at node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:866:5
  at node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:407:3
  at iterateNormalLoaders (node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:10)
  at iterateNormalLoaders (node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:240:10)
  at node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:255:3
  at context.callback (node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
  at Object.transform (node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/transform.js:100:5)
```

**How to replicate**

Create project and install dependencies:

```
npx nuxi init nuxt-webpack
cd nuxt-webpack
npm install @nuxt/webpack-builder html-webpack-plugin html-webpack-inline-source-plugin@beta -D
# prevent dependency error with memfs at the time of writing
npm install json-joy@9.8.0 -D
```

Set `nuxt.config.ts` as such:

```
// nuxt.config.ts

import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin from 'html-webpack-inline-source-plugin';

// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  debug: true,
  ssr: false, // try with and without
  builder: 'webpack',
  webpack: {
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'output.html', // output file name that will be created
        template: 'output-template.html', // template file to use for insertion
        inlineSource: '.(js|css)$', // embed all javascript and css inline
        inject: 'body', // inject script at the end of document body
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin),
    ]
  },
  hooks: {
    // may be needed for successful bundling
    "webpack:config"(configs) {
      // configs[0].module.rules.push(
      //   {
      //     test: /\.vue$/,
      //     loader: 'vue-loader',
      //   },
      //   {
      //     test: /\.html$/,
      //     loader: 'html-loader'
      //   },
      //   {
      //     test: /\.tsx?$/,
      //     use: 'ts-loader',
      //     exclude: /node_modules/,
      //   },
      //   {
      //     test: /\.css$/,
      //     use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      //   },
      //   {
      //     test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|webp|svg)$/,
      //     loader: 'url-loader',
      //   },
      // );
    }
  },
});
```

Add file `output-template.html`:

```
<!-- output-template.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>

<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>Nuxt App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="__nuxt"></div>

    <!-- plugin will insert js here by default -->
</body>

</html>
```

Run build using `npm run generate`.